# Random variable independent of $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, independence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $X$ a random variable. If $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and X is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ we know that $\sigma(X)$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$.
In this case, is it true that $X$ is independent of every $Y$ which is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable? 
I assume yes, since $\sigma(Y)\subseteq{\mathcal{G}}$, am I right?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, thanks.